# MongoDB replication issue - looks fine, but nothing replicating

Tags: mongodb

I am a newbie to MongoDB, and just got a cluster of 3 machines set up to replicate.  All the status stuff looks fine, but none of the data is being replicated.  I do writes to the primary and expect them to show up in the secondaries, but nothing seems to be happening.  I did try slaveOK to see if that would make a difference but it doesn't.  The logs show this error when replication is supposed to be happening:

```
[rsSyncNotifier] replset tracking exception: exception: 9001 socket exception [SEND_ERROR]
```

I don't know what is causing this error.  I have validated connectivity by connecting with Mongo CL both directions.

Any advice?

Here is rs.Status()

```
{
"set" : "mongors",
"date" : ISODate("2013-07-30T21:06:11Z"),
"myState" : 2,
"syncingTo" : "XXXX.cloudapp.net:27019",
"members" : [
    {
        "_id" : 0,
        "name" : "XXXX.cloudapp.net:27018",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 2,
        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
        "uptime" : 8134,
        "optime" : Timestamp(1375216199, 1),
        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-07-30T20:29:59Z"),
        "self" : true
    },
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "name" : "XXXX.cloudapp.net:27019",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 1,
        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
        "uptime" : 7356,
        "optime" : Timestamp(1375216199, 1),
        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-07-30T20:29:59Z"),
        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2013-07-30T21:06:10Z"),
        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2013-07-30T21:06:11Z"),
        "pingMs" : 1
    },
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "name" : "XXXX.cloudapp.net:27020",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 2,
        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
        "uptime" : 2171,
        "optime" : Timestamp(1375216199, 1),
        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-07-30T20:29:59Z"),
        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2013-07-30T21:06:09Z"),
        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2013-07-30T21:06:10Z"),
        "pingMs" : 1,
        "syncingTo" : "beehivemongosvc.cloudapp.net:27019"
    }
],
"ok" : 1
```

}

Replication status:

```
 source:   XXXX.cloudapp.net:27018
 syncedTo: Tue Jul 30 2013 13:29:59 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
     = 2701 secs ago (0.75hrs)
 source:   XXXX.cloudapp.net:27020
 syncedTo: Tue Jul 30 2013 13:29:59 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
     = 2701 secs ago (0.75hrs)
```

Comment: How long did you wait? Did you use a write concern of majority or more than just acking with the primary? Have you tried disconnectng one members and actually looking at the database?

Comment: similar thing happened. I restarted the secondaries, they started replicating. that might work in your case. All the best !.

Comment: I tried restarting the secondaries and nothing changed.  I also tried setting the write concern to majority and it is still the same.  I waited minutes, hours? as I was trying things.  So far, nothing has ever replicated.  I'm not sure if I am missing something fundamental here - I add a document to a collection on the primary and then I am looking for that collection on the secondaries and getting nothing.  (I tried the reverse as well)

Comment: Looking through the logs, I do see an error in the log (question updated)

Answer (score 0):

I did a complete reboot of all the instances, and replication started working.  Tried several more reboots just to make sure and everything kept working.

Lesson:  after initial setup, reboot everything just to make sure.